# Does Buck have anything like Gradle's build variants and product flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build-system

I have been looking into using Buck for a large project, but I want to know if there is an equivalent to gradle's build variants and product flavors that have been so useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debug vs. release builds (i.e., constants in `BuildConfig.java`), there's `android_build_config()`: http://facebook.github.io/buck/rule/android_build_config.html. If you're curious, [the commit that introduced it](https://github.com/facebook/buck/commit/d38375ce11e4874ddb023a9f8ac1e32489669412) explains in detail how `android_build_config()` works and why it has a more efficient implementation than Gradle. Specifically, in Buck, you can build debug and release builds in parallel at the same time, but in Gradle, you cannot.

Although not currently documented, [`android_binary()`](http://facebook.github.io/buck/rule/android_binary.html) has arguments `resource_filter` and `cpu_filters` to restrict the generated APK to the appropriate resources. `resource_filter` could be a list like `['mdpi', 'hdpi']` while `cpu_filters` could be a set like `['arm', 'armv7', 'x86']`. Currently, for each permutation, you have to write a separate `android_binary()` rule, which is admittedly more tedious than how you define things in Gradle. I recommend defining a [macro](http://facebook.github.io/buck/extending/macros.html) to generate all of your `android_binary()` rules to help eliminate boilerplate. We are working to make this easier to do using the built-in rule so developers don't have to create their own macros for this stuff.